# Link_to not showing current text but previously assigned text, cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have the following helper to add a class to to the header link I'm currently on. Originally I had `Home`, `About` and `Clients`. Later I realized I needed to rename the `Clients` link text so I changed the text to "`Gallery`", on page load Clients is still being shown.

**I have tried and things I've noticed:**

- Clearing cache
- Renaming method
- Verified that it IS using index.html.erb
- Using link_to will work fine, it's as if the header_link method stored the first values that were passed in.

This is my helper:

```
def header_link(link_text, link_path)
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
  link_to link_text, link_path, class: "#{class_name}"
end
```

and view:

```
<%= header_link "Home", root_path %>
<%= header_link "About", x_path %>
<%= header_link "Gallery", y_path %>
```

renders:

```
<a class="active" href="/">::before Home </a>
<a href="/x">::before About </a>
<a href="/y">::before Clients </a>
```

Comment: Did you miss a comma between "Gallery" and 'y_path', and 'class name' should be 'class_name'? You're saying replacing it with link_to works?

Comment: You are missing underscore in the helper method `class: "#{class_name}"`. Make sure, variables are correct.

Comment: Sorry about that I wrote the code again as I couldn't copy/paste as I had multiple tabs open in Vim and it messes the clipboard up. Anyways my syntax is fine and the problem persists. I updated my code to what it actually looks like